# How to send POST data to nested Serializer Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, python-2.7, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am writing a sample program where tags can be added to todolist. So i created samples of tags. But when i am having trouble in adding that to The todo serializer.

Here are the serializers i wrote.

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=100)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Tag.objects.create(**validated_data)

class LocationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    latitude = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    longitude = serializers.CharField(max_length=100) 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Location.objects.create(**validated_data)

class ToDoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    work_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
    location = LocationSerializer()
```

I tried sending data to ToDo serializer as POST. But how can i send location and tag details to the API view.

APIView

```
class ToDoList(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ToDoSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How can i pass data as POST to ToDoList. Do i have to write custom post view on ToDoSerializer?

Models

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Location(models.Model):
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ToDo(models.Model):
    work_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request POST data should look like nested structure, as declared in your serializer. AND you should use model serializer for this, because otherwise you'll have to provide custom `create` method on `ToDoSerializer`, because regular serializer doesn't know how to work with nested structures/models.

So, what i propose is:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ToDoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
    location = LocationSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ToDo
        fields = ('tags', 'location', 'work_id', 'id')
```

Your post json should look like:

```
{
    "work_id": 1,
    "tags" : [
        {"name": "blah"},
        {"name": "blahblah"}
    ],

    "location": {
        "latitude": 11.22,
        "longitude": 33.44
    }

}
```

Comment: serializer.create get's called on and returns model instance.
Thusway, you get these tasks by
`instance.tags_set.all()` - default name for such model pair. But you should overwrite this by providing `related_name` to ManyToManyField.

Comment: pls tell what if tags and location are foreign keys in Todo model. and I just want to refer them in new todo object to be created. I just want to create todo object not tag/location objects.

Comment: So since drf doesn't support nested update/create by default, what you want is
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: okay so i have to create my own create method for post requests. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle in create method of the ToDoSerializer serialzier. docs [writable-nested-representations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)

**You can try something like this:**

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    location_data = validated_data.pop('location')
    tag_data = validated_data.pop('tags')
    location = Location.objects.create(**location_data)

    instance = ToDo.objects.create(location=location, **validated_data)

    for dct in tag_data:
        dct.pop('id', None)
        tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(**dct)
        // tag = Tag.objects.create(**dct)
        instance.tags.add(tag)
    return instance
```

Comment: tag, created= Tag.objects.get_or_create(**dct)